# html page height is not equal to window height

Tags: html, css

I have a register page and code is as below but the problem is that the body height of the page is not equal to the browser height

```
<!-- navbar for registration -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-logo" href="/">escapo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!user/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!user/signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span>  Signup</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12 register-login-page">
    <h1 class="escapo-logo h1" >Welcome to escapo</h1>
        <div id="register-form-page" class="row register-form ">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3  ">
            <div ng-view></div>
          </div>  
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried jquery and css to but not able to set body height equal to the browser height.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use JSFiddle and paste your full code, it's not clear what the problem is with only this code

Comment: html body height is 360px but browser window height is 800px